# Catch-all route is incorrectly prioritized over defined templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm on dotnet `7.0.203`; having a very simple problem, which I believe shouldn't be the case. I have a few routes and one catch-all route, with my expectation being catch-all should be executed with the lowest priority; I've even tried to force this using the `Order` prop of the `Route` attribute.

Below you're going to have 3 files,

- the snippet from `Startup.cs` which should show how I'm setting up the routing
- first controller file called `MController.cs` - which has the catch-all route - which has been stealing all the traffic
- another controller file called `RController.cs` - which has an explicit route - but it doesn't work. If I call `localhost:{port}/api/randomized/xyz` my expectation is it'll hit the RController - but it doesn't.

If I use `UseMvc` and drop the `UseRouting` - it works as expected; but I want to get it to work with the newer method and not use Mvc ideally. Any ideas?

```cs
// startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (m_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
        });
    }
    services.AddRouting();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
    services.AddSwaggerGen(ConfigureSwaggerGetOptions);
        // few more service registrations
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{   
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    if (m_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseEndpoints(t =>
    {
        t.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

```cs
//controller 1 - with catch all route

public class MController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{*url}", Order = 1000)] // CATCH ALL ROUTE HERE with explicit lower order.
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ContentResult> SomeHtmlNotImportantAsync()
    {
        
    }
}
```

```cs
// controller 2 - with explicit route

[Route("api/randomized", Order = 1)] // EXPLICIT ROUTE PART 1 with higher order
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public class RController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")] // EXPLICIT ROUTE PART 2
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    // Redacted bunch of things
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeActionAsync(string id)
    {
        // redacted bunch of things
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to get it to work with the newer method and not use Mvc
> ideally. Any ideas?

> [Route("api/randomized", Order = 1)] // EXPLICIT ROUTE PART 1 with
> higher order

Your  RController route order is set 1, but
your  MController is not set order value, so the  default order is 0, 0 with higher order,  so it will excute MController first.

Try to set order at MController like:

```
 [Route("[Controller]", Order = 1000)]
 public class MController : Controller
    {...}
```